# how to style select dropdown with arrow and divider?

Tags: html, css

This is how I've styled the select box so far:

[image]

Changes needed:

1) The arrow should be in the middle
2) The arrow image layer must be greater than the select box so that it will be black in color and not transparent in the background as it is now.
3) Must add divider on the left of the arrow.

This is my css for the above select box:

```
.styled select {
   font-size: 16px;
   outline:none;
   z-index:100 !important;
} 

.styled{
   height: 40px;
   border-radius: 3px;
   background: url("../img/down.png") 96%/ 15% no-repeat;
   z-index:1000 !important;
}
```

And html:

```
<div class="styled">
                  <select name="sorty" id="sorty">
                    <option class='sort' selected disabled>Sort by</option>
                    <option value="review">Review Count</option>
                    <option value="score">Review Score</option>
                    <option value="price_down">Price ($)</option>
                    <option value="price_up">Price ($$$)</option>
                    <option value="distance">Distance (Nearest)</option>
                  </select>
                 </div>
```

Comment: Use jquery multiselect library

Comment: @devpro, but I only need to style it.

Comment: Did u try styled class in select box?

Comment: Apply class on select box this will work

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below css, it may help you

```
    .styled select {height: 40px;border: 0;color: #acacac; background: url(http://maps.vermont.gov/Geocortex/Essentials/ANR/REST/sites/StreamAlterations/viewers/StreamAlterations/VirtualDirectory/Resources/Images/Icons/arrow-down-small-16.png) #FFF right 10px no-repeat;
-webkit-appearance: none;-moz-appearance: none;appearance: none;padding-right: 52px;padding-left: 13px;}
```

Comment: this increased the height but the image remains at top. How to push it in the middle and add vertical divider?

Comment: @Keren You can push image down by (right 20px by background position) Otherwise please send jsfiddle link with image?

Comment: @Keren can you please provide me dynamic link of down.png image? I will demonstrate in jsfiddle.thanks

Comment: here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/0mfyb0wu/   But I couldn't get the image sit properly inside the box here.

Comment: @Keren Please take a look https://jsfiddle.net/dobhchen/2/ and please give right space in image itself (down.png) as well beacuse in this demostrate the arrow down is stick in right. So please right space in image itself.